# Send data to specific computer without user permission? C++

Tags: c++, networking

I've recently had some people to test out my game, programmed in C++, so i can improve it.

I've also added a feature which collects data, and would like to consistently have access to this file (a .txt file)

As I don't have a static IP address, sending it via that would be very tricky.

I need this feature as i dont want to bother the people testing my game all the time for the .txt file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: what platform is your game on?

Comment: can you be more specific? you want to send to the user to send the file or are you sending it to the user?

Comment: @Jay This is an application for Mac

Comment: @user1934851 I want the user to send me a file

Comment: Just send an email? That's all existing infrastructure.

Comment: @MSalters How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your program should send the info to a webserver (I assume you can get a small hosting packet for minimal fee), also your monitoring interface can be a web app.

Also don't forget to print out somewhere in the program that it collects data for testing purposes.